# DAX formula to compare rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet containing several formulas and one of them is quite hard to "translate" it to DAX. Can someone help me with this? I've been trying for a week now but unsuccessful so far. Thanks

```
=IF(AND(B4=B3;N4="Extraordinary Trip";N3<>"Extraordinary Trip");C3;IF(AND(B4=B3;N4="Extraordinary Trip";N3="Extraordinary Trip");E3;C4))
```

B column contains codes; C and E columns are dates. Thanks

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7hIp.png)

Comment: Can you add an example of your data, and any examples of what you have tried?

Comment: Hi i'm sorry! Just added a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7hIp.png

Answer (score 0):

With out looking at the data set it is difficult to answer. However I have dealt with these DAX issues in the past and believe I may be able to help. Some screen shots of your data set or data model would be helpful.
Based off what your telling me your problem might be the issue of selecting a row which is easy in excel but hard in DAX. One way might be
IF( HASONEVALUE(...), VALUES(...), "")
It looks like you may need to add a column to your data model and use the EARLIER function to refer to row prior to the one you are in.
You are not providing us with sufficient info to solve.

Comment: Hi I am sorry! Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7hIp.png

Comment: That makes more sense. So you are trying to add this column into dax instead of excel is that correct? You are not trying to turn this into some sort of measure? In that case you are better off leaving it in excel and just adding your table to the powerpivot data model. Calculated columns should be used only when necessary.

Comment: that's correct, i'm trying to do this because from now on the dashboard will be updated every hour and we created a direct connection between the software x power bi, so the intermediary step (manual formulas on excel) won't happen anymore. that's why i'm struggling so much!! but we are getting there. thank you so much, your suggestion helped a lot